# Image Disappers while Scrolling in Recyclerview in Android

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-imageview, picasso, android-viewholder

I am new to android and trying to load images on button click from url. The image is getting loaded but when i am Scrolling down my activity and trying to scroll up again then images is automatically disappears.

```
public class ImageAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ImageAdapter.ViewHolder>  {

ArrayList<String> urls;
Context context;


public ImageAdapter(Context context,ArrayList<String> urls) {
    this.urls = urls;
    this.context=context;
}
@Override
public ImageAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.viewimage, parent, false);
    return new ViewHolder(view);
}
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    holder.imageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String pos = urls.get(position);
            Log.d("Pos Value", pos);
            holder.setIsRecyclable(false);

            if("".equals(holder)) {
                holder.imageView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                holder.imageView.setImageDrawable(null);
            }
            else {
                holder.imageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                Picasso.with(holder.imageView.getContext()).cancelRequest(holder.imageView);
                Picasso.with(holder.imageView.getContext()).load(pos).memoryPolicy(MemoryPolicy.NO_CACHE).placeholder(R.drawable.image).resize(100,100).into(holder.imageView);
                holder.imageView.setImageURI(null);
            }
        }
    });
}
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return urls.size();
}
public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public ImageView imageView;
    public ImageButton imageButton;
    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        imageView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        imageButton = (ImageButton) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageButton);
    }
}
}
```

MAIN activity

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    recyclerView=(RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.recycleImage);
    layoutManager=new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
    addItemstoArrayList();
    ImageAdapter imageAdapter=new ImageAdapter(getApplicationContext(),urls);
    imageAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    recyclerView.setAdapter(imageAdapter);
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) {
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
    }



}
public void addItemstoArrayList()
{
    urls=new ArrayList<>();
    urls.add("http://kingofwallpapers.com/random-image/random-image-005.jpg");
    urls.add("http://archives.frederatorblogs.com/random/files/2008/04/b-corrupted-by-random-noise-bit-error-rate0020.gif");
    urls.add("https://lh3.ggpht.com/VnSav7pXcExlls8O5xV3m7cN2M3UGHZLkkHkvZtwEBtrsPCXzRtOGlzvg6GzYCV-9PAS=w300");
    urls.add("http://schooltutoring.com/help/wp-content/uploads/sites/2/2014/07/Math-Review-of-Random-Numbers.jpg");
    urls.add("http://static.tumblr.com/b5e9590d4f2aa32199cf5ba25105838a/8va8xfq/nlDnpamkw/tumblr_static_64tfx6f0lesk4ss4c8g8wcos0.png");
    urls.add("https://storage.googleapis.com/imgfave/image_cache/1359429986261769.jpg");
    urls.add("http://images2.fanpop.com/image/photos/8800000/Cool-Pic-s-random-8889999-437-320.jpg");
    urls.add("http://images6.fanpop.com/image/photos/35500000/Cool-pics-random-35514813-500-313.jpg");
    urls.add("http://s8.favim.com/orig/72/beautiful-photography-random-tumblr-Favim.com-675117.jpg");
    urls.add("http://s8.favim.com/orig/72/beautiful-photography-random-tumblr-Favim.com-672024.jpg");
}
}
```

Comment: your Picasso call looks really complicated, can you try it with a basic call first? i.e., Picasso.with(context).load(pos)into(holder.imageView). Also, for finding the issue, remove the code that makes the view GONE, and also the code that nulls the image URI for the viewholder. I'm not 100% that these will be causing your issues, but best to start with a blank slate

Comment: I have tried this also but still the same issue.

Comment: I think it's to do with your logic - you don't show an image until the viewholder is clicked. onBind happens every time your viewholder is laid out on screen. Maybe have some flag in your viewholder class to keep track of "clicked" and if it has been clicked load the image, if not, just set the click listener

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

### ImageAdapter + updated Viewholder

```
public class ImageAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ImageAdapter.ViewHolder> {

ArrayList<String> urls;
Context context;


public ImageAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<String> urls) {
    this.urls = urls;
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public ImageAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.image_viewholder, parent, false);
    return new ViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    String pos = urls.get(holder.getAdapterPosition());
    Log.i("Pos Value", pos);
    holder.onBindViewHolder(pos);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return urls.size();
}

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public ImageView imageView;
    public Button button;
    boolean clicked = false;

    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        imageView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.iv_main);
        button = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.ib_main);
        button.setText("click");
    }

    public void onBindViewHolder(String url) {

        if (clicked) {
            Picasso.with(itemView.getContext())
                    .load(url)
                    .placeholder(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                    .resize(100, 100)
                    .into(imageView);
        } else {
            button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    clicked = true;
                    Picasso.with(itemView.getContext())
                            .load(urls.get(getAdapterPosition()))
                            .placeholder(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                            .resize(100, 100)
                            .into(imageView);
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
}
```

### MainActivity + Picasso global error listener (optional)

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private ArrayList<String> urls;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    populate();
    setUpRecyclerView();
    setPicassoErrorListener();
}

public void setPicassoErrorListener() {
    Picasso.Builder picassoBuilder = new Picasso.Builder(this);

    picassoBuilder.listener(new Picasso.Listener() {
        @Override
        public void onImageLoadFailed(Picasso picasso, Uri uri, Exception exception) {
            Log.e("PICASSO", uri.toString(), exception);
        }
    });

    // Picasso.Builder creates the Picasso object to do the actual requests
    Picasso picasso = picassoBuilder.build();

    try {
        Picasso.setSingletonInstance(picasso);
    } catch (IllegalStateException ignored) {
        // Picasso instance was already set
        // cannot set it after Picasso.with(Context) was already in use
    }


}

private void setUpRecyclerView() {
    RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler);
    LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
    ImageAdapter imageAdapter = new ImageAdapter(getApplicationContext(), urls);
    imageAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    recyclerView.setAdapter(imageAdapter);
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) {
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
    }
}

public void populate() {
    urls = new ArrayList<>();
    urls.add("http://kingofwallpapers.com/random-image/random-image-005.jpg");
    urls.add("http://archives.frederatorblogs.com/random/files/2008/04/b-corrupted-by-random-noise-bit-error-rate0020.gif");
    urls.add("https://lh3.ggpht.com/VnSav7pXcExlls8O5xV3m7cN2M3UGHZLkkHkvZtwEBtrsPCXzRtOGlzvg6GzYCV-9PAS=w300");
    urls.add("http://schooltutoring.com/help/wp-content/uploads/sites/2/2014/07/Math-Review-of-Random-Numbers.jpg");
    urls.add("http://static.tumblr.com/b5e9590d4f2aa32199cf5ba25105838a/8va8xfq/nlDnpamkw/tumblr_static_64tfx6f0lesk4ss4c8g8wcos0.png");
    urls.add("https://storage.googleapis.com/imgfave/image_cache/1359429986261769.jpg");
    urls.add("http://images2.fanpop.com/image/photos/8800000/Cool-Pic-s-random-8889999-437-320.jpg");
    urls.add("http://images6.fanpop.com/image/photos/35500000/Cool-pics-random-35514813-500-313.jpg");
    urls.add("http://s8.favim.com/orig/72/beautiful-photography-random-tumblr-Favim.com-675117.jpg");
    urls.add("http://s8.favim.com/orig/72/beautiful-photography-random-tumblr-Favim.com-672024.jpg");
}
```

}

### image_viewholder.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical">
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/iv_main"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:scaleType="center"/>
<Button
    android:id="@+id/ib_main"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

### AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="iblocks.co.uk.imageadapter">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">


    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

hope it helps chum

Comment: Thanks for the answer bro but its working only when single image is downloaded onClick of button but when multiple images are downloaded and scrolled again then images are getting disappeared again.

Comment: the only reason this would stop working is if the activity or view is destroyed - are you talking about this not working after you rotate the screen? It works perfectly for me

Comment: Did you ever get this working the way you wanted it to? I can send you this project ^ with the code working if you like.. and I can explain how to use onSaveInstance state for activities and recycler views too if you like

Comment: For sure sir, i want to learn about this. if you can help then it will be really helpful for me.

Comment: Sorry I don't know why I didn't see that, did you get it working in the end? You're probably not seeing them stay clicked as every time you rotate the phone, the device basically cycles its lifecycle for that case, and as a result, recreates the view, which recreates everything not explicitly kept outside of the regular logic. So, you want to override onSaveInstanceState and write your own logic for persisting your objects in your recycler and their state - that way, you can re-init the recycler at the correct position and with the correct data, instead of rebuilding each time

Comment: Also, (likely more relevantly) when recyclerviews recycler their views, they call either onBindViewholder  or onCreateViewholder depending on the situation and some other factors. It's likely yours are being cycled and recreated. In this case, it helps to save state in the objects themselves, or keep track of which ones are currently clicked/selected etc (or in your case, have had an image downloaded) Picasso should handle the rest

Comment: There are also hacky things you can do like just tell it not to recycle and similar operations that stop it from fully recycling views. There is a lot of info on these, but it can be confusing, especially when working with complex objects and viewholders that you can't feasibly just change and add fields to. If you're really locked in, it isn't completely horrible to just keep track of your "activated" viewholders in something like a hashmap and use this to determine if your viewholders should be expanded or not on onBind/onCreate